# Block consumption on topic until the consumption is done on another topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two Kafka topics: topic_a and topic_b with data already injected.

For the first deployment of my application, I need to consume messages from topic_a before consuming messages from topic_b.

In fact, the calculation triggered upon receiving message on topic_b assume that we already have data received on topic_a.

That's why I want to block consumption on topic_b until consumption on topic_a is completed.

What is the best way to achieve this with the minimum of steps?

Answer (score 0):

You can check consumer-lag on "topic a", but if there is an active producer sending data to that topic, it may never happen; Kafka has no definition of "complete consumption", other than that property. To put another way - based on the above logic, you'd want to also "stop topic_b consumption" if at least one event from topic_a arrives?

> receiving message on topic_b assume that we already have data received on topic_a

Kafka topic joins are possible with Kafka Streams API, if you need to correlate that data.